# Android ImageView refresh in Loop

Tags: android, multithreading, image, canvas

I am new to Android and I need to create an Image Map i.e. I have a custom map in a bitmap and I need to display and move a cursor (Location Indicator) over the Image Map. I have used Image View to display the image and canvas to draw the cursor over that image and this works fine in below code:

```
WalMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);
bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WalMap.getWidth(), WalMap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
canvas = new Canvas(bMap);
canvas.drawBitmap(WalMap, 0, 0, null);
icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cursor);
icon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 30, 30, false);
canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 90, 100, paint);
image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bMap));
```

Now, I need to refresh the position of cursor after say every X seconds. When I try to do this in a loop or in a thread the app gets force close on my phone. Here is the attempt on using threads:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            doMySearch(width,height,move,canvas);
            while (true) {
                sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
            move=100;
            doMySearch(width,height,move,canvas);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } };    public void doMySearch(int xaxis, int yaxis, int ymove,Canvas canvas) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(icon, xaxis / 2 + 90, yaxis / 3 + ymove + i, paint);
            image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bMap));
    }
```

Also, if I try this in a loop, the canvas still keeps previous position of cursor on the display and doesn't refresh upon redraw. Will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO UPDATE UI ON THREAD

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

@Override
public void run() {
try {
  while (!isInterrupted()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        doMySearch();
      }
    });
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
}
};

t.start();
```

### TO UPDATE YOUR LOCATION

```
//Create a new image bitmap and attach a brand new canvas to it
drawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),     Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
uLocationCanvas = new Canvas(drawBitmap);

uLocationCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

uLocationPaint = new Paint();
uLocationPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), drawBitmap);

//Draw the image bitmap into the cavas
uLocationCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

uLocationPaint = new Paint();
uLocationPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
//Draw everything else you want into the canvas, in this example a rectangle  with rounded edges
uLocationCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, uLocationPaint);

//Attach the canvas to the ImageView
floorImage.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), drawBitmap));


hope this will help
```